# Responsive navbar icon absolute position not working

Tags: html, css

Following this tutorial (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_topnav_responsive.asp), I managed to make the navbar from my website look like this:

[image]

It looks great, but when I click the icon, this happens:

[image]

The icon goes to the top right corner and I don't know why. I tried changing a lot of settings in the CSS< but nothing worked. Here is the HTML:

```css
  #nav-div {
  font-family: 'Manaspace Regular';
  font-size: 1vw;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  position: static;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#responsive-icon {
  display: none;
}

.topnav a {
  color: green;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.active,
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ffd800;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 705px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {
    display: none;
  }
  .topnav #responsive-icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  #home-link {
    float: left;
  }
  #nav-div {
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    min-width: 360px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #nav-div a,
  #nav-di a.icon {
    font-size: 7vw;
  }
  .topnav.responsive {
    position: relative;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="topnav" id="nav-div">
  <a href="{% url 'home' %}" id="home-link">Home</a>
  <a href="{% url 'play' %}" class="menu_list" id="play-link">Play</a>
  <a href="{% url 'scores' %}" class="menu_list" id="score-link">Scores</a>
  <a href="{% url 'source' %}" class="menu_list" id="source-link">Source</a> {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <a href="{% url 'logout' %}" class="menu_list" id="join-link">Log out</a> {% else %}
  <a href="{%url 'join' %}" class="menu_list" id="join-link">Sign in</a> {% endif %}
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" id="responsive-icon" onclick="dropDownMenu()">&#9776;</a>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function dropDownMenu() {
            var nav = document.getElementById("nav-div");
            if (nav.className === "topnav") {
              document.querySelector('#home-link').style.width = '70%';
                nav.className += " responsive";
            } else {
             document.querySelector('#home-link').style.width = '20%';
                nav.className = "topnav";
```

That is the only thing left to my website to be ready, so any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

looks like the onclick="dropDownMenu()" function is changing the positioning value.

according to the tutorial, the function adds a class to your icon-div. check, if the value of position in the added class is different to the original one.

edit:

"Position absolute takes the document out of the document flow. This means that it no longer takes up any space like what static and relative does. When position absolute is used on an element, it is positioned absolutely with reference to the closest parent that has a position relative value."

```
.topnav.responsive a.icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

right: 0; and top: 0; takes your icon to the top-right corner. But with position: absolute, it leaves it's parents flow. it now acts like an element of body. Try without these values or calculate the space you need. (top: (height of the element in top of it))

Comment: The only thing that this function changes is the class of the navbar and the width of the 'home' link. I will add the JS code in the question

Answer (score 0):

Here how I done it:
Simply moved the icon to be the second element of the navbar and made it appear with CSS when the screen get to a determined width.

```
<a href="{% url 'home' %}" id="home-link">Home</a>
 <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" id="responsive-icon" onclick="dropDownMenu()">&#9776;</a>
 <a href="{% url 'play' %}" class="menu_list" id="play-link">Play</a>
 <a href="{% url 'scores' %}" class="menu_list" id="score-link">Scores</a>
 <a href="{% url 'source' %}" class="menu_list" id="source-link">Source</a>
```

And then got rid of this piece of code:

```
.topnav.responsive a.icon {
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
   top: 0;}
```

I still don't know why it didn't work like in the tutorial, though.